# Photo filter - pixelate (mozaik), rotate 45deg and take color of these squares?

Tags: javascript, html, image, graphics

Need help with algorithm for to something like this :

ORIGINAL:
[image]

AFTER EFFECT:
[image]

And after this effect i want to take color of every square ( save it as X,Y,RGB);

First idea was just resize image. If i need 32x32 image i resize normal image to 64x64 and just take every second pixel. And also every second row i move to x+1.

Any better ideas? For me important is get colors info. I dont' need image, just colors.

**EDIT:**

I found this code : http://www.exorithm.com/algorithm/view/pixelate .

So what i think. First rotate image 45deg, procces it by this code, save color of each square, then procces this data colors by matrix transform. Is it even possible to rotate pixels data by 45 deg?

P.S. I'm doing it in javascript, jQ etc.

Comment: rotate 45 degrees, scale down, scale up, rotate back 45 degrees

Comment: @samgak ok, nice and simple. But how get color info of each square?

Comment: one way might be to render it to a canvas and then call getImageData http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp

Comment: Yes, i know i need getImageData but... In my idea its easy to get colors. However in your  this little 45deg squares =/= pixel.